# Next.js API route resolved without sending a response

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js

I have a project made with React/Next.js.

This is the file directories.

[image]

What I am trying to do is have the user `GET` - `/api/grademate/pay` and return the `success` page.
Fetching `/api/grademate/pay` works without a problem.
The problem is, while testing, the `success` page does not load when I try to visit it manually.

This is what my `index.js` file looks like inside the `success` folder:

```js
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from '../../../../styles/Home.module.css'

export default function Success() {
    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <Head>
                <title>Payment Success</title>
                <meta name="description" content="Your payment was successful!" />
                <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
            </Head>

            <main className={styles.main}>
                <h1 className={styles.title}>
                    Payment Successful!
                </h1>
            </main>

        </div>
    )
}
```

When I try to visit `/api/grademate/pay/success`, nothing happens and the page just loads and this error is printed:

> API resolved without sending a response for /api/grademate/success,
> this may result in stalled requests.

Keep in mind I am new to the world of React and Next.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Next.js, the `api` folder is used for API routes *only*.

Your normal page components should *not* be inside the `api` folder, they should live under the `pages` folder directly.

For instance, your `pages` folder structure could look like the following.

```
pages/
  api/
    grademate/
      pay.js
  grademate/
    pay/
      success/
        index.js
  _app.js
  index.js
```

Your `Success` page can then be accessed at `/grademate/pay/success`.

Comment: Thank you! This worked :)